# Nested Models attribute localization for error messages in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a deeply nested models form.

When a nested model attribute is in error the error messages is displaying:

> List items identifier url may not be blank.

Which is:

> Model_name + attribute + localization file error message

The correct message should be:

> Item link url may not be blank.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :014 > ListItem.human_attribute_name("identifier")
=> "Item Link"
```

Localization is otherwise working fine except for nested model attribute names in error messages.

Looks like it was a [bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3177-rails-234-and-nested-models-attributes-localization) in 2.3.4 that was fixed, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

the following is working for me. I've a Course model and a OfflineCourse Model. OfflineCourse is nested in Course.

The following YAML works correctly form me. Hope this helps

```
  course:
    title: Titolo
    subtitle: Sottotitolo
    description: Descrizione
    abstract: Abstract
    audience: A chi è rivolto?
    topic: Argomenti
    typology: Tipologia
    stars: Stelle
  course/offline_courses:
    start_date: Data inizio
    end_date: Data fine
    location: Luogo
    schedule: Programma
    visible: Visibile
    city: Città
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the the "proper" way to solve this, but this will work.

In your localization file, you probably have something like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      list_item:
        identifier: Item Link
```

This will work as long as you address it from the nested model directly. Rails validations appears to go via the parent model, so you need something like:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      list_item:
        identifier: Item Link
      parent_model:
        list_item:
          identifier: Item Link
```

To me this seems to break the DRY principle because you have to repeat the human readable name at the nested level too, but this should work for you.

Comment: I could swear I tried that and it didn't work. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Also try `list/list_item:` as per http://www.soulcutter.com/blog/2013/localization-of-nested-attributes-in-rails-3-dot-2/